# How to make a bootable USB out of the folder in which the data of windows 8 setup is there?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, usb, iso-image

I copied windows 8 CD to my HDD and now, i want to convert that folder to an iso please tell e how to do that. so that i could burn the iso to my usb and make my usb bootable
How to make a bootable USB out of the folder in which the data of windows 8 setup is there?

Comment: Just insert that disk once again and make a proper ISO. Simpliest solutions are usually the best.

Comment: While I agree with @gronostaj, I guess you're looking for [this](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/11194-how-to-create-a-windows-vista-7-8-installation-disc-bootable-using-imgburn/) or [this](http://www.windowsvalley.com/create-windows-vista-and-windows-7-bootable-dvd/). I've never tried it myself so I have no idea if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to ESD, of the windows 8 you downloaded from the website, all you have to do is start the install, and it will ask you how you want to do it, you can install from the program launch itself, create a dvd or a boot-able USB, if you have a valid product code go here, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only and you can do the options I just stated.

hope this helps you out, if not provide more information on what your wanting to do, I might be able to assist.

If you have the orginal DVD, do this, create and iso of it then download this link , it a s tool microsoft made to do just what you want to. http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool